React Valtio higher order function that uses a dynamic function
I have the current state (example):
const state = proxy({
    field: {
      fn: (n) => n + 1,    // the implementation of fn does not matter, it is just a function that does something
      hof: (n) => state.field.fn(n ?? 10),
   }
})

hof is the higher order function that uses fn (depends on fn). Sometimes fn does something different. I update it like this:
state.fields.fn = (n) => n + 20

If I access the fn property within a component, it rerenders on change, as expected
const { fn } = useSnapshot(state)

The problem is that if I access only hof, the component does not rerender
const { hof } = useSnapshot(state)

Even if I update fn, accessing hof does not make the component rerender.
What I tried:
get hof() { return (n) => state.field.fn(n ?? 10) }  // make hof a getter that returns a function

The problem here is that getters execute on each state update to check if it has changes. And since this creates a new instance of function every time, it rerenders the component every time something in that proxy changes, even if the component does not use that property.
I tried to solve it like this:
const f = (n) => state.field.fn(n ?? 10)  // define the function as variable
...
get hof() { return f }

this way the returned function does not get recreated each time, but this time the component stops rerendering on fn change as well
How to create higher order function as Valtio proxy property that uses a dynamic property (dynamic function)?
